# Insert a string to another string in C

Tags: c, for-loop, insert, c-strings

I need to insert a character string to another character string.
I'd write my own code and it's work very well until I put SPACE character in insert character string.
I need to find out what is the problem of my code and How I can fix it.

```
//Insert string in another string
#include <stdio.h>

//Function to count number of characters in a string
int numOfChars(const char string[]);
//Function to insert string to another string
void insertString(char string[], char insert[], int position);

int main()
{
    char str[20]= "145";

    insertString(str, "23", 1);

    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}

int numOfChars(const char string[])
{
    int counter = 0;

    while(string[counter] != '\0')
        counter++;

    return counter;
}

void insertString(char string[], char insert[], int position)
{
    int i, j;
    int lenght1 = numOfChars(string);
    int lenght2 = numOfChars(insert);

    int finalLenght = lenght1 + lenght2;

    for(i=lenght1, j=0; i<finalLenght; i++, position++, j++)
    {
        string[i] = string[position];
        string[position] = insert[j];
    }

    string[finalLenght] = '\0';

}
```

Example 1 :
Main string : 145
Insert string : 23
Position : 2
Result : 12345

Example 2 with blank space :
Main string : 145
Insert string : 23[SPACE]
Position : 2
Result : 123 54

Comment: Clearly you're working under constraints that you have not expressed in the question, such as about (non-)use of standard library functions.  It would be helpful to everyone if you specified those constraints.

Comment: [`strlen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3p.html) already exists and you could use it in your code.  Also [`memmove()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3p.html) will be helpful.

Comment: The `insertString()` code is all there already, @Cubo78.  Scroll the code frame.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know how to use library for this purpose But I need to understand How does C works

Comment: This would be an excellent example on which to start learning how to use a debugger.  If you're using an IDE then it almost certainly includes an integrated one.  Otherwise, there are standalone debuggers, such as gdb.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito I know strlen exist But I write my own code to understand how does this library works

Comment: @Magic, I'm not asking about what you know.  I'm asking you to express, in the question, the relevant constraints on acceptable answers to the question.

Comment: Hint: the problem has nothing to do with the specific characters in your strings, as you can verify by inserting the two-character string "2 ".  The string *lengths* are relevant, however.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I don't know why I didn't scroll.. Magic, the problem is the for loop inside insert string. Ask yourself: where do I have to start writing the part of the original string after the insertion?

Comment: Note that `numOfChars()` is available as standard — it's called `strlen()`.  Also note that 'length' is not spelled 'lenght', but I grant you that you're consistent in your misspelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop

```
for(i=lenght1, j=0; i<finalLenght; i++, position++, j++)
{
    string[i] = string[position];
    string[position] = insert[j];
}
```

is incorrect because independent on the given position all characters from the source string stating at position `position` are written after the end of the source string.

Also the function `insertString` should be declared like

```
char * insertString(char string[], const char insert[], size_t position);
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be implemented.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t numOfChars( const char s[] )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] != '\0' ) ++n;

    return n;
}

char * insertString( char s1[], const char s2[], size_t pos )
{
    size_t n1 = numOfChars( s1 );
    size_t n2 = numOfChars( s2 );

    if ( n1 < pos ) pos = n1;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n1 - pos; i++ )
    {
        s1[n1 + n2 - i - 1] = s1[n1 - i - 1];
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
        s1[pos+i] = s2[i];
    }

    s1[n1 + n2] = '\0';

    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 20 };
    char s1[N] = "123";

    puts( insertString( s1, "AB", 0 ) );

    char s2[N] = "123";

    puts( insertString( s2, "AB", 1 ) );

    char s3[N] = "123";

    puts( insertString( s3, "AB", 2 ) );

    char s4[N] = "123";

    puts( insertString( s4, "AB", 3 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
AB123
1AB23
12AB3
123AB
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `string[i] = string[position];` to `string[position+lenght2] = string[position];` should solve the problem.

While copying over the elements of `string[i]` to their proper places, the length of the string to insert should be considered in addition to the `position` variable. In other words, you should shift the characters in `string` by the number of elements that need to be inserted in the middle.